# Resizing + stretching with vipsthumbnail?

Tags: image, image-processing, vips

I'm using vipsthumbnail to resize images via the command line.

I would like to know if there is a way to resize an image and ignore its aspect ratio, so that no matter what size if I passed 5x500 I would get a 5px by 500px image.

I can't fine anything in the documentation.

I'm using the lib on macOS.

Comment: Feature request to ignore aspect ratio in `vipsthumbnail` has been created on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/issues/648).

Comment: Nice, user1480019.

Comment: Released as part of 8.6. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From libvips 8.6, `vipsthumbnail` supports imagemagick-style size specifications. For example:

```
vipsthumbnail k2.jpg --size "50x50!"
```

will resize to 50x50 pixels whatever the size of the input image. There's a chapter in the docs about using `vipsthumbnail`:

http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html

Comment: Is there any method for php library for  ignore its aspect ratio in vips resize funcion?

Comment: Try `['size' => 'force']`.

Comment: $im = $im->resize($ratio, ['size' => 'force']);

I try above one, it gives me error no property named `size'

Comment: You need `thumbnail`. Try `$image = Vips\Image::thumbnail('some/filename.tif', 50, ['height' => 50, 'size' => 'force']);`. Don't use `resize` unless you have to, it's much slower, but if you must use it, there's a `vscale` parameter to set the vertical scaling separately. Check the docs: https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-resample.html#vips-resize